# When to use natural vs. artificial harmonics

Tags: notation, strings, harmonics

[image: String harmonics homework exercises]

I am working on the above homework assignment regarding string harmonics. I'm stuck on exercise #2. What are the rules or guidelines for determining whether a pitch should be played via a natural or an artificial harmonic?

Comment: @BrianTowers Says who? If it's edited to ask an actual question (it doesn't at the moment), then it's on-topic. https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Do you want to ask an actual question that someone can answer?

Comment: Hi Marie Labellarte. I've rewritten your question so that it will be suitable for this site. However, if I have misunderstood what you intended to ask, or in any way misrepresented your intentions, you can roll back my changes, or post a comment and I'll do so.

Comment: I feel like I have to get my hands on a viola to figure out the specifics, but 1) in general, I'd use natural harmonics whenever they're possible to generate the desired pitch and artificial when they aren't, and 2) for extra credit, it would be nice to arrange things so that the left hand doesn't have to make any bigger shifts than it has to.